# How to specify the icons theme in qooxdoo?

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

I want to have an icon in my DateField in the Qooxdoo framework.

How do I specify the icon set to use?

This is my config file. As you can see I want to use the default theme.

```
"let" :
  {
    "APPLICATION"  : "myapp02",
    "QOOXDOO_PATH" : "../qooxdoo-2.1.1-sdk",
    "QXTHEME"      : "qx.theme.Modern",
    "API_EXCLUDE"  : ["qx.test.*", "${APPLICATION}.theme.*", "${APPLICATION}.test.*", "${APPLICATION}.simulation.*"],
    "LOCALES"      : [ "en" ],
    "CACHE"        : "${TMPDIR}/qx${QOOXDOO_VERSION}/cache",
    "ROOT"         : "."
  },
```

But it doesn't use any icons in the DateField. Instead it simply display the date and the right part of the DateField (where you're suppose to click to get the full calendar) is empty.

I also tried to use:

```
"QXTHEME"      : "myapp02.theme.Theme",
```

And this is my Theme.js file:

```
qx.Theme.define("myapp02.theme.Theme",
{
  meta :
  {
    color : myapp02.theme.Color,
    decoration : myapp02.theme.Decoration,
    font : myapp02.theme.Font,
    icon : qx.theme.icon.Tango,
    appearance : myapp02.theme.Appearance
  }
});
```

But to no avail. (still no icons in the DateField)

I placed a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310728/how-do-i-place-a-label-on-the-datefield.

So to reiterate, how do I use an icon set Tango or Oxygen to place an icon in my DateField like in this tutorial: http://demo.qooxdoo.org/2.1.1/demobrowser/#widget~DateField.html?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to install the icon set (Tango icon set for example) before using the createapplication.py script.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to install anything besides the qooxdoo SDK if you want to use Tango or Oxygen icons, as they are included. If there is an icon missing from your DateField you should make sure you re-generate your app, and then watch the console of your browser for messages of unknown images or HTTP requests resulting in a 404 (if you are running the app through a web server).